# Run Oracle XE 18c on Windows: Oracle Home User or pre-existing domain user instead of local virtual account?

Tags: oracle-xe, oracle18c, oracle-home

For commercial versions of Oracle 12c it is possible to appoint an existing Windows domain account to run Oracle Windows services - 'Oracle Home User'.
But for Oracle XE 18c we have no such option during installation on Windows.

May be some post-installation workaround is available to use this feature or something alike?

Our goal is to access files on remote NT share via UTL_FILE package. 
But it requires to set up permissions on domain level - and it is hardly possible for local virtual accounts which are appointed for Oracle services by default installation.

Answer (score 1):

After I have been told by Oracle ACEs that no Oracle Home User is possible for XE18c, I decided to try some old tricks.

After clean installation of XE18c on Windows Server 2012R2:

1) I've stopped OracleServiceXE in Services MMC.

2) I've changed LogOn account properties in OracleServiceXE Properties tab from 'NT Service\OracleServiceXE' to 'MYDOMAIN\myuser' which has necessary permissions on remote share.

3) I've deleted a key HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDB18Home1\ORACLE_SVCUSER_TYPE (which was set to 'V').

4) I've changed  a value of key HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDB18Home1\ORACLE_SVCUSER to 'MYDOMAIN\myuser'.

5) I've started OracleServiceXE in Services MMC.

Here I was able to log on locally under 'sys as sysdba', run 'shutdown' and 'startup' and then connected via SQL Plus from remote workstation. 
No problem at all.

6) The obvious next steps inside Oracle to prove the concept (creation a user in XEPDB1, registration share UNC path as a directory, granting permissions, test of UTL_FILE sample for new user) were successfull too.